# ActionBar shows either all actions or none, putting all into the overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

My app targets SDK 17, I'm testing with Android 4.x emulator (with the Support Library and ActionBarSherlock so that the ActionBar is available for Android 2.x).

I've got 6 menu items for one of my Activities. There are 3 which are vital and need to be shown all the time. The remaining 3 can be in the overflow menu, but if there is room for a 4th or 5th icon, I want as many showing as possible.

My problem is that the ActionBar seems to only show ALL or NONE. I set `android:showAsAction="always"` for the first 3 and then `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for the last 3. However, I shows NONE of them in the ActionBar, but it adds the overflow menu action (three vertical dots) and then shows all 6 actions in the overflow menu.

I've been iterating and testing, trying to figure out how it decides to behave. If ANY of the 6 options have `ifRoom` then ALL of them get put into the overflow menu, which seems stupid.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get some of the actions shown and have the overflow menu... hold the **overflow**?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <group android:id="@+id/group" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_btn_add"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="Add"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/calculateNPV"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon_npv"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="NPV"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/calculateIRR"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon_irr"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="IRR/YR"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:icon="@drawable/content_email"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="@string/share"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="Graph"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/deleteReorder"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_clear_playlist"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="Delete/Reorder Cashflows"/>
        </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Hi @KennyWyland, although this question is already answered and I agree that the use of `<group>` is odd, I have 1 question: why not use `android:showAsAction="always"` for your 3 vital items and `ifRoom` for the rest. It seems only logical to me - you can't have it all right?

Comment: @fuzzybee I was trying to do what you're describing, but the app refused to behave. I'd have 3 with always and the rest with ifRoom and it would show NONE of them. That was the issue. The `<group>` was the problem (I used it b/c the tutorial I followed during my first Android app used it). When the items were inside the `<group>`, it treated them all as one unit for always vs ifRoom. Removing the group allowed it to work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting rid of `<group>`. It is eminently possible that `<group>` causes the overflow behavior to work on the entire group rather than individual items.

Comment: This is indeed the behavior. The code dictating this behavior is in `flagActionItems` of [`ActionMenuPresenter`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuPresenter.java#L353). Specifically, [this block](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuPresenter.java#L463-474).

Comment: /facepalm Thank you so much. I originally wrote this menu xml a year and a half ago and the group tag was essentially invisible to me. It now works exactly as I would have expected. Thank you!

Comment: Well, almost exactly. I notice that even if there IS room, if I set it to "ifRoom" it seems to always show it in the overflow. That's not a real problem though and you definitely fully answered my question... I just wanted to also note that weirdness. :)